# disable direct access to git repo

Tags: linux, git

I have set up a local git repo on a linux machine and have users check in and check out from it:

```
/myfolder/gitrepo/
```

How can I disable any modification access to that folder directly unless they come from git commit requests. I would like to do so even for my own username. I don't have root/sudo access.

Comment: Are your users committing _directly_ into the repository, or are they committing into their own clones and pushing into yours?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me what you are doing here?  Is this a [bare repository](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)?  You can't really push to a non-bare repo, so?

Comment: I don't have a remote repo. I just created a local repo and I was hoping I can use that local repo for multiple users.

Comment: Right, so what you want to do then is create a bare repo, that you will treat as the official repo, then set permissions so people can clone/push/pull from it as fits your requirements.

Comment: @Zoredache: Correct. That is what I need!